# How do i use iText to have a landscaped PDF on half of a A4 back to portrait and full size on A4

Tags: itext

I have a landscaped form lay on a top half of A4 page, I want it to be rotated  and enlarge to a portrait layout size fill up the A4 then saved before it is faxed out. Otherwise, the fax service program will fax it out with only partial info. Here is my attempt, result is the same as the input pdf. This is my first day on programming using iText, all the google not getting me what I want. Please let me know if you can help. Thanks,

```
public class CopeALandscapePdfFiletoPortraitPdfFile {
//public static final String SRC = "resources/pdfs/landscapeForm.pdf";
public static final String SRC = "resources/pdfs/potraitForm.pdf";
public static final String DEST = "results/stamper/portraitFormAfterCopy.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException
{   
    copyPdf();
}

private static void copyPdf() throws IOException, DocumentException
{
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
    document.newPage();
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfDictionary page;
    PdfNumber rotate;
    for (int p = 1; p <= n; p++) {
        page = reader.getPageN(p);
        rotate = page.getAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);

        if (rotate == null) {
            page.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(90));
        } else {
            page.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber((rotate.intValue() + 90) % 360));
        }

    } 
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
    stamper.close();

    PdfImportedPage ipage = writer.getImportedPage(stamper.getReader(), 1);
    cb.addTemplate(ipage, 0, 0);

    document.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Is your form interactive or not?

Comment: not interactive, i also found out it is a fax image, so I now need to get the image out of the pdf and rotate the image and have it enlarged. But I am not able to rotate PDXObjectImage, looking for a way ...

Comment: Does the answer help? Or do you need additional help on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As you want to enlarge the PDF anyways, I would put enlarging and rotating into one afine transformation. Thus:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, RESULT);
document.open();

double sqrt2 = Math.sqrt(2);
Rectangle pageSize = reader.getPageSize(1);
PdfImportedPage importedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
writer.getDirectContent().addTemplate(importedPage, 0, sqrt2, -sqrt2, 0, pageSize.getTop() * sqrt2, -pageSize.getLeft() * sqrt2);

document.close();
```

*([EnlargePagePart.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext5/content/EnlargePagePart.java))*

E.g. for this page

[image: original page]

it generates

[image: zoomed, rotated upper half]